# throw without arguments for failure signalling

Tags: c++

Is it ok to just call `throw;` from constructor if something goes awry, and you have no idea how to recover?

The idea is to let the app crash with a dump, as the state is unknown. Or should you always specify an argument?

From MSDN I only found that it rethrows if there is no argument, but no idea what happens if there is no initial exception to rethrow.

Comment: If you want to get a crash, just `abort()` or `assert(false)`. That will provide a dump (depending on your system configuration) and is less confusing than an error message saying that the program terminated because of a `throw;` with no prior exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there's no exception currently being processed `throw;` will lead to [`terminate()` being called immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981400/57428) and that will end your program abnormally. That is not very convenient - you'll have less information about what happened compared to throwing a meaningful exception. You could have thrown a meaningful exception, catch it at the top level (like `main()`), write some diagnostics and then end the program.

Comment: There is a slight advantage in a program dump: you can inspect what the state of the whole program is, and try to analyze how the system got there. I tend throw an exception when you can recover, and die when you cannot, so that most state can be processed.

Comment: Hmm, yes, the stack unrolling is unwanted in this case. But Terminate doesn't save stack info as well, does it?

Answer (score 17):

No. `throw;` is a special syntax that re-throws current exception. It only makes sense inside `catch` blocks (or code called from one) to continue propagating the exception.

Just use:

```
#include <stdexcept>
...
throw std::runtime_error("some description");
```

or even just

```
throw "some description";
```

but the later is uglier to handle and just generally frowned upon.

Comment: Technically you can use `throw;` anywhere.

Comment: don't use `throw "some description";`, what you throw should derive from `std::exception`, or else the boogeyman will come and get you.

Comment: @sharptooth: Edited "may only be used" -> "only makes sense" to be formally correct.

Answer (score 2):

An ASSERT might make your life easier to dignose what's going wrong

Comment: @Maxim: if you test suite is comprehensive, you don't need the test in release builds (I usually keep the test but throw instead...)

Comment: @Maxim If you disable asserts for the "release" build - usually you get what you deserve : a random program state, if very lucky a crash. Murphy's law.

Comment: @VJo: You are not using asserts correctly. Have you heard of checking error codes and exceptions?

Comment: @Maxim I did. Asserts are to prevent impossible parameters being passed to a function. The problem with disabling asserts is it is most likely a micro-optimization. btw I assumed that the ASSERT macro (from the answer) is throwing an exception.

Comment: @VJo: make a google search for "c++ assert" and re-read the first hit then.

Comment: @Maxim I am not sure how to respond to the last comment, as I am not sure if you are joking or not. The hit I got is from cplusplus.com and says that the asserts to capture programming errors, which can pass the testers. Reread my comment again

Comment: "Therefore, this macro is designed to capture programming errors, not user or running errors, since it is generally disabled after a program exits its debugging phase."

Comment: I think ASSERT or was it VERIFY is nop'ed in release builds. So ASSERT(DooFoo()); will not be called at all.

Answer (score 2):

While technically you can call it, it won't do what you'd like.

The simplest solution is to call `throw std::runtime_exception("thrown from Foo");`, which at the same time gives some feedback about what was going on.

Comment: Just make your fatal exception class capture the stack trace.

Comment: @Maxim: yep very handy too, in fact all our exceptions do, it's just so easier to trace them back this way.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "no idea how to recover" what you mean I presume is that at this point you do not know how to handle the error?

Perhaps you are not getting the point of exceptions. You throw information: that the exception occurred and why. The call-stack is then unwound to the point where it can be handled. At that point in the code we know how, if possible, to recover.

Comment: Yes, some impossible, unexpected condition happened, like undocumented error in third party library, out of memory error, bit flip, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do that because throw without argument and without an active exception just calls `terminate()` which by default calls `abort()`. I prefer calling `abort()` directly, it requires less cognitive effort to recognize what is going on.