# What does a single "throw;" statement do?

Tags: c++, exception, throw

These days, I have been reading a lot the [C++ F.A.Q](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) and especially [this page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html).

Reading through the section I discovered a "technique" that the author calls "exception dispatcher" that allows someone to group all his exception handling in one handy function:

```
void handleException()
{
  try {
    throw; // ?!
  }
  catch (MyException& e) {
    //...code to handle MyException...
  }
  catch (YourException& e) {
    //...code to handle YourException...
  }
}

void f()
{
  try {
    //...something that might throw...
  }
  catch (...) {
    handleException();
  }
}
```

What bothers me is the single `throw;` statement: if you consider the given example then sure, it is obvious what it does: it rethrows the exception first caught in `f()` and deals with it again.

But what if I call `handleException()` on its own, directly, without doing it from a `catch()` clause ? Is there any specified behavior ?

Additionally for bonus points, is there any other "weird" (probably not the good word) use of `throw` that you know of ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read this on your linked page? http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.15  'In this example, the statement `throw;` means "re-throw the current exception."'

Comment: @Fred Larson: Absolutely. But in the case where there is no "current" exception, what happens ?

Comment: I found the answer, but @dalle beat me to it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you do a `throw;` on its own, and there isn't a current exception for it to rethrow, then the program ends abruptly. (More specifically, `terminate()` is called.)

Note that throw; is the only safe way to re-throw the current exception - it's not equivalent to

`catch (exception const & e) { throw e; }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might be part of another question but is surely related: could you explain the difference between calling "throw;" and "throw e;" in your last statement ? I wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: @ereOn: I believe at least one difference is that `throw;` will preserve the original exception type, while `throw e;` may slice.

Comment: @Fred Larson: I thought slice may happen only when catching by value. But you might be right (I'm not sure at all). Is there anyone to confirm that ?

Comment: Yes - `throw e;` throws a new exception with the static type of e, not the dynamic type - so it can slice if e is polymorphic.

Comment: Additionally, the second example would only rethrow the current exception if it derived from `std::exception`, correct?

Comment: @NHDaly Yes. Any other exception would not be caught (and so wouldn't need rethrowing anyway). But nice people don't throw things that don't derive from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 41):

Yes, it specified behavior, it will call terminate;

> 15.1, para 8: If no exception is presently being handled, executing a
>   throw expression with no operand calls
>   terminate() (15.5.1).

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer as well: I accepted Alan Stokes's answer because he currently has a lower reputation than you. He also provided a detailed and accurate answer. Upvoted this one for fairness tought. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

That's so-called exception handler. It rethrows the "current exception" if any. If there's no exception currently being handled [`terminate()` will be called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981400/57428).