# std::thread created thread not handling exceptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am creating a few std::threads that will be detached. I would like to have these running for a long time and would like these to handle exceptions themselves.

I create a thread using std::thread(Function) and have called detach before releasing the mutex and where Function does following:

```
void BlockStart() noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> sync(lock);
}
void Function()
{
   BlockStart();
    try 
    {
        throw;
     }
     catch(...)
     {
         std::cerr << "Caught something...\n";
     }
}
```

Everytime I run this code, the exception handler is not called. The default handler of std::terminate() is called which calls abort.

How do I get an std::thread started thread to handle exceptions?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378736/1619294

> If you do a `throw;` on its own, and there isn't a current exception for it to rethrow, then the program ends abruptly. (More specifically, `terminate()` is called.)

You may want to do something like

```
void Function()
{
    try 
    {
        SomeOtherFunction();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught something...\n";
    }
}
```

Also, note that the lock guard + mutex inside the `BlockStart()` function will only block within the function's duration, and will not persist after it returns. The solution would be to have the lock guard lock inside `Function()`

```
void Function() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> sync(lock);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `throw` by itself re-throws the current exception, but that only works when called inside of a `catch` block.  If you try to call `throw` by itself inside of a `try` block when there is no current exception, `terminate()` is called and your app dies.  You **must** tell `throw` *WHAT* to throw when inside of a `try` block, eg:

```
void Function()
{
    BlockStart();
    try 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("something bad happened");
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught something... " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Also, using `std::lock_guard` inside of `BlockStart()` is useless.  `sync` is a local variable, so it will go out of scope and release the mutex when `BlockStart()` exits.  It only makes sense to use it if it actually does something while the mutex is locked, eg:

```
void BlockStart() noexcept
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> sync(lock);
    // do something here while the mutex is locked...
}
```